# Resizing image containing column to same size as sibling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout with two columns. On the left, a variable size image with some descriptive text below, on the right, some text with headings, data fields and so on.

If the image is large, it looks ok:

[image]

(note here the image is using `.img-responsive` and is actually about 320x320 when viewed, depending on browser viewport size).

If the image is small, I don't like the alignment:

[image]

Ideally I would prefer the small image appear vertically and horizontally centered, with the descriptive text ("150x150") aligned to the bottom.

Is this possible, ideally using Bootstrap 3 classes, otherwise is it possible at all?

Here's my current code (note the white border is not included because this is from a custom Bootstrap style sheet): http://www.bootply.com/szAeKcB7HP

Comment: Have you considered using the [Bootstrap Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)? It has a "middle" vertical alignment option.

Comment: Nice idea, that kind of works, although at the moment I'm getting a very truncated width on the `.media-body`. Also, the Bootstrap template I use modifies the `.media*` classes a bit. I might try a little more if there are no other suggestions...